# Why are stations in Japan rendered as a mix of red, yellow and orange in Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps, cartography, color, transportation, japan

When you go by a large train station in Japan in Google Maps, you can see that it, along with its surroundings, is often heavily colored (see [this example](https://www.google.com/maps/@34.6937912,135.1942664,17z), [another example](https://www.google.com/maps/@35.7095233,139.7749513,17z)).

[image: First example]

I would like to know whether this is more of a national convention, something specific to Google Maps or simply something done by the transport authority?

Comment: If it is the way Google Maps shows it, its almost certainly Google styling / cartography. I'm not familiar with that area in Osaka, but looking at an area like Shinjuku (Tokyo), it appears to be showing different parts of the station / lines belonging to different companies. Your example in Ueno shows that - JR to the west (Yamanote Line) and Tokyo Metro to the east (Hibiya Line).

Comment: Red= underground shopping area. Orange and yellow= see this Google blog [Areas of interest](https://www.blog.google/products/maps/discover-action-around-you-with-updated/).

Comment: @Kazuhito I think your suggestion should be converted in an answer.

Comment: @Kazuhito Thanks. To me, areas of interest are beige, here distinct yellow/orange areas are displayed (yellow in both examples, orange in the second example). Also screenshots show that yellow areas were here before areas of interest (slide 7 of http://bit.ly/2tDnYpg). I guess it's about important lines/lanes.

Comment: If the color renders its importance, it does not make sense putting striking color on local lines, not on the national trunk line. Your attached picture shows *Tokaido main line*, which connects main cities including Tokyo-Osaka,  in modest color.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be a general geography/cartography issue, not GIS-centric.

Comment: @CécileBertau, the best way for saying *thanks* here is accepting the answer you found as the most useful for solving your issue.

Comment: I understand OP is not satisfied with the answer. A confusion here is the historical background (data origin) and how it was implemented  in Google's API. I can add some pointers if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Red: Underground shopping area
- Orange and yellow: see this Google blog [Areas of interest](https://www.blog.google/products/maps/discover-action-around-you-with-updated/)

Answer (score 4):

Red is not shopping area. Red is station undeground area together with all station exits. Still you can find some shops in thick part but rare. Especially it's impossible to find any shops in narrow red parts. You can check that info comparing [map](https://www.google.com/maps/@35.6720705,139.7671577,17.53z) from Higashi Ginza station to Otemachi station through Ginza, Hibiya and Tokyo stations with [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NUi-NQF0AmM).  There are some shops but mostly it's just a passage way.

Dark red parts are pedestrian bridges over the ground overlapping underground ways. You can see them if switch to 3D view.

Yellow are major roads but it can be buggy in different zoom levels.